# Why is Regex.Match not matching the same strings as Regex.Matches?

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net

I made a find and replace dialog with a regex option. There is a button to test a regex, highlighting all matches, and a button to find individual matches. With some regular expressions both methods make the same matches. Other regular expressions yield no matches with `Regex.Match`, but behave as expected with a collection of `Regex.Matches`. I have tried different `RegexOptions` when assigning the Regex, but haven't found any option that makes it behave as desired.

The goal here is to be able to test a regex, with `ButtonTestRegex`, then to be able to select each match, with a Find or Replace button.

```
Public rtb as RichTextBox

Private Sub ButtonTestRegex_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    rtb.Select(0, rtb.TextLength)
    rtb.SelectionColor = Color.Black

    Dim rgx As New Regex("(duplicate of )*([0-9]:+)*")

    Dim matches As MatchCollection = rgx.Matches(rtb.Text)
    For Each match In matches
        rtb.Select(match.index, match.length)
        rtb.SelectionColor = Color.Red
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub ButtonFind_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    rtb.Focus()
    rtb.selectionstart = 0
    rtb.selectionlength = 0
    Dim rgx = New Regex("(duplicate of )*([0-9]:+)*")
    Dim match As Match = rgx.Match(rtb.Text)
    If match.Value <> "" Then
        rtb.SelectionStart = match.Index
        rtb.SelectionLength = match.Length
     End If
End Sub
```

With a RichTextBox containing the following:

> 1:remainder
>
> duplicate of 1:remainder
>
> duplicate of duplicate of 1:remainder

The code above will match all text except "remainder" with `ButtonTestRegex_Click()` (as expected). Nothing will be matched with `ButtonFind_Click()`. The code is being executed, and it does work with some regexs, e.g. `[0-9]`.

This code sample is abbreviated for clarity. My question is, why does `Regex.Match` not match anything in this case but `Regex.Matches` does?

Comment: The answer is most probably that your `"(duplicate of )*([0-9]:+)*` can match an empty string. With Regex.Matches, there is no problem since this method will scan every position in the string and with Regex.Match, this will match the beginning of the string if there is no text matching the optional pattern at the start or it should return a match if the text at the start of the string matches the optional pattern. The solution is to modify the pattern to match non-empty strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you have a space or something at the start of the text selected by your `RichTextBox`. At that point, it makes total sense. Look at your regular expression:

```
(duplicate of )*([0-9]:+)*
```

That will match the empty string. So for example, if you find all the matches of that against `"x"`, you'll find one match before the `x`, and one match after the `x`.

When you call `Match`, that finds the *first* match - which it does successfully, but matches an empty string. When you call `Matches`, it will retrieve *all* the matches - and there are a lot of them. Here's a small C# console app to show them all, assuming a space at the start of the text:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var regex = new Regex("(duplicate of )*([0-9]:+)*");
        var input = @" 1:remainder
duplicate of 1:remainder
duplicate of duplicate of 1:remainder";
        foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(input))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(match.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

The output of that starts like this:

```
0
2
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
15
0
```

... but there's a *lot* of output.

It's not entirely clear what you were trying to match, but you probably want to make sure that empty strings *don't* match your regex.

Comment: So it was making the matches. I just didn't click the find button enough to see it. Bonus lesson for me here is using the console to see the actual matches instead of relying on visual changes in the RichTextBox. Thank you.

Comment: @codingcoding: I find that in most cases, a quick console app is a *hugely* efficient way of debugging. No UI to get in the way, just the code you need :)